# Passing arguments to UILabel [ 2 ] *

Tags: objective-c, xcode, arguments, uilabel

I'm trying to call a method of the below (Scroll animation class) type from a viewcontroller class.

```
-(void)CreateLabel:(CGRect )frame andLabel:(UILabel *[NUM_LABELS])label andview:(UIView *)view;
```

I got some errors when I tried passing the argument. Any suggestion on how to call this?

This is how I called that method

```
ScrollAnimation *newAnimation = [[ScrollAnimation alloc] init];
[newAnimation CreateLabel:CGRectMake(0, 50, 300,30) andLabel:animateLabel[NUM_LABELS] andview:self.view];
```

I have the error

```
 /Volumes/Red Drive/CarTransition/CarTransition/ViewController.m:120:66: Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'UILabel **' is disallowed with ARC 


 /Volumes/Red Drive/CarTransition/CarTransition/ViewController.m:120:66: Incompatible pointer types sending 'UILabel *__strong' to parameter of type 'UILabel **'
```

Create Label Method :

```
  -(void)CreateLabel:(CGRect )frame andLabel:(UILabel *[NUM_LABELS])label andview:(UIView *)view{
for (int i = 0; i<NUM_LABELS ; i++){

    if(i == 0){
        label[0] = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width,frame.size.height)];
        label[i].text = @"MINI ";
    }else if(i == 1){
        label[1] = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y - 40 ,frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
        label[1].text = @"COOPER ";
    }else if(i == 2){
        label[2] = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.x-120 ,frame.size.width,frame.size.height)];
        label[2].text = @"STYLING";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide code where `animateLabel` is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is asking an array of pointer.

here's a dirty example:

```
- (void)passArgument:(NSObject *[])anObject total:(uint)total{
    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        NSLog(@"list --> %@", anObject[i]);
    }
}
```

Now the call:

```
NSString* object[5] = {@"a", @"b", @"c", @"d", @"e"};
[self passArgument: object total: 5];
[self passArgument: &object[2] total: 3];
```

1. Note: object is an array of pointer, (*)
2. &object[2] is the address of a pointer (&**)
3. object[1] is a pointer to a    pointer (**), and that's not what you
   want